# Smoothing vertices based on deformed mesh shape?

Tags: armature, shape-keys

I'm trying to create corrective shape keys for a mesh, but one limitation I'm hitting is that even with the Armature modifier set to show in Edit mode and adjust the Edit cage, trying to move things along vertex normals or use the Smooth Vertex tool in Edit mode seems to be basing its result on the base mesh shape, because I get very different results when trying it on a deformed mesh and when I bake the armature modifier.

The sculpt mode smoothing tool *does* seem to work based on the deformed shape, so clearly it's not the case that the maths was too complex for Blender to support such a thing at all, so I'm assuming I must have something set wrong.

What do I need to do to get the normals and smoothing tool to work based on the deformed mesh shape in Edit mode? (I could theoretically resort to the smoothing tool in sculpt mode, but I would really rather have access to both options).